# TFTP: Server Error: (2) Access Violation

Tags: linux, tftp, xinetd

I am trying to send a file to TFTP server using below command:

`tftp -p -l test.txt xx.xx.xx.xx`

And TFTP usage is:

> BusyBox v1.13.2 (2011-03-24 18:58:44 CDT) multi-call binary
>
> Usage: tftp [OPTION]... HOST [PORT]
>
> Transfer a file from/to tftp server
>
> Options: -l FILE Local FILE -r FILE Remote FILE -g Get file -p Put file

When I tried to send a file with the above command, I got this error: `tftp: server error: (2) Access violation....`

But if I create test.txt (file name that I needed to send) in the server manually and then try to transfer to server, it uploaded successfully.

How can I send the file without manual creation?

I am using xinetd service for tftp server, and below is its config file.

> /etc/xinetd.d/tftp : service tftp { protocol = udp port = 69 socket_type = dgram wait = yes user = root server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd server_args = /tftpboot/ disable = no }

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I debugged the issue.

```
# tail /var/log/syslog
```

The output of the above command said tftpd was serving files from `/srv/tftp` but there is no mention of `/srv/tftp` in `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp`.

Also this post helped to debug the issue: http://toddharris.net/blog/2011/06/19/debugging-xinetd-at-system-launch/. 
Running xinetd in debug mode did not cause this problem.

The culprit was the tftp line in `/etc/inetd.conf` as mentioned in the following link:
http://www.beer.org/blog/category/tech-stuff.html
Most probably when xinetd runs as a daemon, the `/etc/inetd.conf` takes precedence over the config files in `/etc/xinetd.d` directory and that is why this issue occurs when xinetd runs as a daemon.

Comment out the tftp line in `/etc/inetd.conf` and restart xinetd and that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-c` to your `server_args`:

```
server_args = -c /tftpboot/
```

See the [tftpd(8) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tftpd).

Comment: thanks gary..made change and restart the xinetd service. But now its showing me "tftp: timeout error". My /tftpboot's ownership and permission are nobody:root and drwxrwxrwx.  Can you help me more on this.